# How to block out light though a sliding glass door

Tags: windows

I have glass sliding doors between my bedroom and living area.  The light from the loungeroom and the flicker of the tv comes through the glass doors and makes it hard to sleep.  I am wanting to find out how I can block out the light from coming through to the bedroom.

Comment: https://m.kohls.com/product/prd-1404586/eclipse-blackout-thermal-patio-door-curtain-panel-100-x-84.jsp.    Available in many stores and websites the blackout curtains work very well

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/Blackout-Blocking-Windows-Non-Permanent-Darkening/dp/B003ZJ88DY

Answer (score 1):

I would just treat it like a sliding glass door to the outside and hang the blinds of choice or some sort of black out curtain as mentioned above. A more long term solution would be to change from a slider to french doors that have the blinds or louvers built into the window portion of the door.